# Installing Debian on Kaby Lake machine: difficulties with X.org

Tags: debian, intel-graphics

I just recently bought a new PC, and I am unable to install debian system proprerly. Now I will provide you in most detailed way my configuration and status:

**PC:**

- CPU: i7 7700K (Kaby Lake with Intel HD graphics 630)
- MB: MSi Z270 SLI PLUS
- RAM: Kingston HYPER 2x8GB RAM @ 2400MHz (12CL)
- SSD: intel 600 256GB

**DISTRO:**

Debian GNU/Linux 8.7 Jessie

After the instalation of the system, OS started properly however xserver runned only in low resolution (1024x768).

I assumed that it is a driver problem, so I have installed some drivers from this [site](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/) with no succes, then I tried some new kernels:

- 3.16.43  X
- 3.18.20  X
- 4.1.39   X
- 4.4.59   X
- 4.9.20   M
- 4.10.8   M
- 4.11-rc5 M

With kernel with sign X (see above) the situation was the same as with original kernel `3.16.0-4`, however with ones with M sign, was different: It looked that it started with a proper resolution, however xserver crashed in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` there was message:

> Screens found,but none have a usable configuration

and then

> Fatal server error: no screens found

I tried to change some `xorg` configurations or some settings in i915 module, but with no success

any help would be appreciated

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

After removing all manually installed kernels, installing kernel 4.9 from jessie-backports and removing the `xserver-xorg-video-intel` driver, the command:

```
grep EE /var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

will return

```
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[     2.670] (EE) Failed to load module "intel" (module does not exist, 0)
[     2.671] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[     2.671] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[     2.672] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[     2.672] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[     2.672] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[     2.672] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[     2.672] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[     2.672] (EE) Device(s) detected, but none match those in the config file.
[     2.672] (EE) 
[     2.672] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[     2.672] (EE) 
[     2.672] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[     2.672] (EE) 
[     2.672] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

**EDIT 2:**

the whole `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` :

```
[     2.630] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[     2.630] Build Operating System: Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64 Debian
[     2.630] Current Operating System: Linux Bobor 4.9.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.13-1~bpo8+1 (2017-02-27) x86_64
[     2.630] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 root=UUID=97e2dfda-29d2-44b4-ac08-80ea49496bb6 ro quiet
[     2.630] Build Date: 11 February 2015  12:32:02AM
[     2.630] xorg-server 2:1.16.4-1 (http://www.debian.org/support) 
[     2.630] Current version of pixman: 0.32.6
[     2.630]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[     2.630] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[     2.630] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sun Apr  9 19:23:09 2017
[     2.631] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[     2.632] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[     2.632] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[     2.632] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[     2.632] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[     2.632] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[     2.632] (==) Automatically adding devices
[     2.632] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[     2.632] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[     2.634] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[     2.634]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     2.636] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
    built-ins
[     2.636] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[     2.636] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[     2.636] (II) Loader magic: 0x559d23f1ed80
[     2.636] (II) Module ABI versions:
[     2.636]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[     2.636]    X.Org Video Driver: 18.0
[     2.636]    X.Org XInput driver : 21.0
[     2.636]    X.Org Server Extension : 8.0
[     2.637] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:5912:1462:7a59 rev 4, Mem @ 0xde000000/16777216, 0xc0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000f000/64, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[     2.637] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[     2.638] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[     2.644] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     2.644]    compiled for 1.16.4, module version = 1.0.0
[     2.644]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 8.0
[     2.644] (==) AIGLX enabled
[     2.644] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 0
[     2.644] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 1
[     2.644] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 2
[     2.644] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 3
[     2.644] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[     2.644] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[     2.645] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module intel
[     2.645] (II) UnloadModule: "intel"
[     2.645] (II) Unloading intel
[     2.645] (EE) Failed to load module "intel" (module does not exist, 0)
[     2.645] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[     2.645] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[     2.646] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     2.646]    compiled for 1.16.4, module version = 0.9.0
[     2.646]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     2.646]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 18.0
[     2.646] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[     2.646] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[     2.646] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     2.646]    compiled for 1.15.99.904, module version = 0.4.4
[     2.646]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     2.646]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 18.0
[     2.646] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[     2.646] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[     2.646] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     2.646]    compiled for 1.15.99.904, module version = 2.3.3
[     2.646]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     2.646]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 18.0
[     2.646] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[     2.646] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[     2.646] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[     2.646] (++) using VT number 7

[     2.647] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[     2.647] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[     2.647] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[     2.647] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[     2.647] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[     2.647] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[     2.647] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     2.647]    compiled for 1.16.4, module version = 0.0.2
[     2.647]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 18.0
[     2.647] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[     2.647] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[     2.647] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[     2.647] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[     2.647] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[     2.647] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     2.647]    compiled for 1.16.4, module version = 0.0.2
[     2.647]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 18.0
[     2.647] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[     2.647] vesa: Ignoring device with a bound kernel driver
[     2.647] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[     2.647] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[     2.647] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[     2.647] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[     2.647] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[     2.647] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[     2.647] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[     2.647] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[     2.647] (EE) Device(s) detected, but none match those in the config file.
[     2.647] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[     2.647] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[     2.647] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[     2.647] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[     2.647] (EE) 
[     2.647] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Kaby Lake (and any Intel graphics since Broadwell), you need to install a new kernel and firmware from Jessie backports; as root:

```
echo deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list
apt-get update
apt-get -t jessie-backports install linux-image-amd64 firmware-misc-nonfree
```

You also need to *remove* (paradoxically) the X.org Intel video driver (as indicated in the [package description](https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/xserver-xorg-video-intel): the X server can use the kernel’s mode-setting features without a separate video driver):

```
apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

When you run this, if `apt-get` tells you it’s going to remove other packages, don’t let it do so; you might need to install `xserver-xorg-video-dummy` to satisfy dependencies.

You should also remove the kernels you installed manually.

Once all that’s done, reboot and you should find your system working much better.

If that fails though, you can try installing the backported Intel driver instead (along with the new kernel and firmware):

```
apt-get -t jessie-backports install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

Comment: Would you care to elaborate why removing the intel driver? I might be having a similar problem with FreeBSD and xorg

Comment: @Rui see the update. Does FreeBSD have the necessary mode-setting support in the kernel?

Comment: Interesting....I maybe ok then by the description, I had no idea it was deprecated...I will post a few FreeBSD questions between today and Monday. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: So far no luck ... I still have the same error message

Comment: In past few months I have installed debian on several Broadwell and Skylake machines (e.g. i7 5930K, i7 6850K, ...), and this behaviour is new to me.

Comment: Do you have an `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file? If so, you should rename it.

Comment: I do not have such file, I think all of my configuration is stored in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/`

Comment: You mention that you changed some settings, and I see from the logs that your system is explicitly looking for the “intel” driver (which it shouldn’t). Where did you make those changes?

Comment: To ensure that no previous settings would change the behaviour, I made a new installation of OS from scratch. Nevertheless, only non standard thing I have done: for some reasons, installation of efi-grub fails. One have to install it manually (the `chroot` thing). But don't think that has to do something with my case.

Comment: Yes, `efi-grub` wouldn’t have anything to do with your problems. Could you post your full `Xorg.0.log` somewhere? The “Device(s) detected, but none match those in the config file.” error indicates that there is some explicit (and incorrect) configuration somewhere, hopefully the full log will show what... Once you’ve done that, `sudo apt-get -t jessie-backports install xserver-xorg-video-intel` will install a backported Intel driver and get you up and running (albeit not “properly”, but who cares if it works).

Comment: Installing intel driver from jessie-backports indeed made it up & running

Comment: OK, I’m not sure what’s going on there, but I’ve added the variant that works for you to the answer.

Comment: @StephenKitt posted it. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/361243/using-native-1366-x-768-resolution-in-a-lenovo-ideapad/361244

Comment: `E: The value 'jessie-backports' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources`

Comment: @Menasheh if you have a new question, please [ask it as a new question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) instead of commenting on an old question.

Answer (score 0):

Debian Buster Intel graphics issue:

```
    1) Display cannot wake up after sleeping
    2) The whole the computer is suddenly freezing and overheating from time to time
    3) dmesg shows below errors:



firmware: failed to load i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin (-2)
Direct firmware load for i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin failed with error -2
Failed to load DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin. Disabling runtime power management.
DMC firmware homepage: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/i915
```

The computer details:

```
 user@debian-buster:~$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model name'
    model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz
    model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz
    model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz
    model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz
    model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz
    model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz
    model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz
    model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz
    user@debian-buster:~$
```

Chinese motherboard “GKBR1-VERC” with AMI BIOS:

```
user@debian-buster:~$ sudo dmidecode -t 2
dmidecode 3.2
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.1.1 present.

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: Default string
    Product Name: Default string
    Version: Default string
    Serial Number: Default string
    Asset Tag: Default string
    Features:
        Board is a hosting board
        Board is replaceable
    Location In Chassis: Default string
    Chassis Handle: 0x0003
    Type: Motherboard
    Contained Object Handles: 0
```

BIOS version:

```
user@debian-buster:~$ sudo dmidecode --type bios
dmidecode 3.2
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.1.1 present.

Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 26 bytes
BIOS Information
    Vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
    Version: 5.12
    Release Date: 07/01/2018
    Address: 0xF0000
    Runtime Size: 64 kB
    ROM Size: 16 MB
    Characteristics:
        PCI is supported
        BIOS is upgradeable
        BIOS shadowing is allowed
        Boot from CD is supported
        Selectable boot is supported
        BIOS ROM is socketed
        EDD is supported
        5.25"/1.2 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/2.88 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
        Serial services are supported (int 14h)
        Printer services are supported (int 17h)
        ACPI is supported
        USB legacy is supported
        BIOS boot specification is supported
        Targeted content distribution is supported
        UEFI is supported
    BIOS Revision: 5.12

Handle 0x004B, DMI type 13, 22 bytes
BIOS Language Information
    Language Description Format: Long
    Installable Languages: 1
        en|US|iso8859-1
    Currently Installed Language: en|US|iso8859-1

user@debian-buster:~$
```

Intel integrated graphics:

```
user@debian-buster:~$ lspci -kk | grep -A3 VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
user@debian-buster:~$
```

Kernel:

```
 user@debian-buster:~/OS/deb/firmware$ uname -r
 4.19.0-8-amd64
 user@debian-buster:~/OS/deb/firmware$
```

The solution:

Install the following package:

```
xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

Create the following xorg config file:

```
 user@debian-buster:~$ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-intel.conf 
    Section "Device"
      Identifier "Intel Graphics"
      Driver "intel"
    Endsection
    user@debian-buster:~$
```

Create the below directory:

```
 user@debian-buster:~$ ls -ld /lib/firmware/i915
    drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 20 21:01 /lib/firmware/i915
    user@debian-buster:~$
```

Download from debian repo the below non-free package:

```
firmware-misc-nonfree_20190114-2_all.deb
```

Unpack the package and find the missing firmware:

```
dpkg -x firmware-misc-nonfree_20190114-2_all.deb .



 user@debian-buster:~/OS/deb/firmware$ find | grep kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin
    ./lib/firmware/i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin
    user@debian-buster:~/OS/deb/firmware$
```

Put the firmware to /lib/firmware/i915/ directory:

```
sudo cp ./lib/firmware/i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin /lib/firmware/i915/
```

Udate initramfs for the current or for all kernels:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```

After reboot the firmware should be loaded:

```
 user@debian-buster:~/OS/deb/firmware$ sudo dmesg | grep kbl
    [sudo] password for user: 
    [    0.016859] ACPI: SSDT 0x000000007F7E1F68 000724 (v02 INTEL  xh_kbl-r 00000000 INTL 20160422)
    [    3.942920] i915 0000:00:02.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin
    [    3.943311] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin (v1.4)
    user@debian-buster:~/OS/deb/firmware$
```

No more freezes, display wakes up correctly after touching the mouse or keyboard,
HTH

Comment: It was running without any issues a couple of weeks, then I've got an additional freeze and overheating again. Installed intel-microcode package. Will let it run some time, and see how it goes.