# Using native 1366 x 768 resolution in a Lenovo Ideapad

Tags: xorg, freebsd

I have a Lenovo Ideapad 100S 14'' IBR-14'' Intel Celeron CPU N3060 @ 1.60GHz, 32GB SSD, 4GB RAM, based in the Broadwell chipset, running FreeBSD 12.0.

I have been trying to configure xorg to use the native upper resolution of 1366x768 without success.

I installed two display drivers:

```
sudo pkg install xf86-video-intel xf86-video-scfb
```

The Intel i950 display driver is giving an error and aborting with several combinations of configurations, that I have got using `xrandr`.

The scfb/syscons display driver is only working in 640x480, and ignoring any directives about size; was not able also to use the vesa display driver without much success (vesa deprecated, or the wrong combination with vt drivers, did not bother to check).

(I tried to configure in the Device section of the x.org config file both the "intel" and the "scfb" driver).

As in `/usr/local/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/xorg.conf`

```
Section "Device"
    Driver      "scfb"
    #Driver      "intel"
EndSection
```

The Intel errors are very similar to this thread - [Installing Debian on Kaby Lake machine: difficulties with X.org](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/356738/installing-debian-on-kaby-lake-machine-difficulties-with-x-org/356744?noredirect=1#comment632224_356744) actually.

What to do?

Output of xandr [image: xrandr]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ironically, in FreeBSD the answer is pretty much similar to the thread pointed in the question.

> You also need to remove (paradoxically) the X.org Intel video driver
>   the X server can use the kernel’s mode-setting features without a separate video driver

Whilst it is referring to Linux, the same seems to be happening with FreeBSD.

So what it was done:

```
sudo pkg delete xf86-video-intel
```

Also in `/boot/loader.rc.local`:

```
mode 2
```

See [Determining EFI text modes supported by notebook](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/361270/determining-efi-text-modes-supported-by-notebook/361271#361271)

(In the Lenovo is the EFI text mode for the higher resolution, 170 cols x 40 rows - 1366x768  )

The actual `/usr/local/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/xorg.conf` being used is, where the "scfb" display driver is configured:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    ModulePath   "/usr/local/lib/xorg/modules"
    FontPath     "/usr/local/share/fonts/misc/"
    FontPath     "/usr/local/share/fonts/TTF/"
    FontPath     "/usr/local/share/fonts/OTF/"
    FontPath     "/usr/local/share/fonts/Type1/"
    FontPath     "/usr/local/share/fonts/100dpi/"
    FontPath     "/usr/local/share/fonts/75dpi/"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load  "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Keyboard0"
    Driver      "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Mouse0"
    Driver      "mouse"
    Option      "Protocol" "auto"
    Option      "Device" "/dev/sysmouse"
    Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor0"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "scfb"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "Card0"
    Monitor    "Monitor0"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

After these changes, and rebooting, xorg started in the 1366x768 resolution.

From the FreeBSD [wiki](https://wiki.freebsd.org/Graphics/SCFB)

> If an accelerated graphics driver is not available for your FreeBSD
>   system, an alternative is to use the scfb driver. At the time of
>   writing, this is a common option for laptops with Broadwell or Skylake
>   chipsets from Intel with integrated graphics, until the intel DRM
>   driver is updated to include support. Whilst the scfb driver does not
>   provide accelerated graphics, and is missing some features like
>   brightness adjustment and support for external displays, it works fine
>   on built-in laptop displays for simple desktop use and even playing
>   videos.
>
> The system must be using the new vt(4) (aka Newcons) console for the
>   scfb driver to work. This is the default if the system was booted with
>   UEFI, but not if it was booted using (legacy) BIOS mode. Some laptops
>   must be booted using UEFI mode for the scfb driver to work.

Disclaimer: this is the easiest solution. Apparently there patches out there for making the Intel driver work, however it involves compiling source code.