# Using xorg in a Lenovo Ideapad

Tags: xorg, openbsd

I have a Lenovo Ideapad 100S 14'' IBR-14'' Intel Celeron CPU N3060 @ 1.60GHz, 32GB SSD, 4GB RAM, based in the Broadwell chipset, running OpenBSD 6.1.

I have been trying to configure xorg without success. Both when letting it boot by default by configurations, or defining the Intel driver, I have got the following error back:

```
(EE)
Fatal server error:
(EE) no screens found(EE)
(EE)
```

`/var/log/Xorg.0.log` also show it seems to try the following Drivers/Modules: glx, intel, vesa and vbe.

See also my related FreeBSD question about this `xorg` bug at [Using native 1366 x 768 resolution in a Lenovo Ideapad](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/361243/using-native-1366-x-768-resolution-in-a-lenovo-ideapad)

How can I use X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run X with success, I ended up using the `wsfb` frame buffer OpenBSD driver.

to be able to do that, I created the file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` with the following contents:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Card0"
    Driver "wsfb"
EndSection
```

From `man wsfb`:

> ```
> wsfb is an XFree86 driver for the OpenBSD wsdisplay frame-
>  buffer devices. This is a non-accelerated driver. The fol-
>  lowing framebuffer depths are supported: 1, 8, 16 and 24,
>  given that the wsdisplay device underneath supports them.
>  A StaticGray monochrome visual is provided for depth 1, all
>  visual types are supported for depth  8 and a TrueColor
>  visual is supported for the other depths. Multi-head confi-
>  gurations are supported.
> ```

Comment: Don't change the files in `/usr`. Use `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`with the same content as your example but changing "wsfb" to "modesetting".

Comment: @RufoElMagufo Thanks for your comment, changed it to /etc... "modesetting" does not work for me.

Comment: 6.2 will probably include better support for broadwell.

Comment: Indeed, I am looking forward for better bhyve support too