# Is there a way to reduce screen brightness or change its colors when using the SCFB driver on FreeBSD?

Tags: x11, drivers, freebsd, brightness

#### Background

I am running FreeBSD 12-CURRENT on Lenovo Yoga 3 14 and I use [the SCFB graphics driver](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=scfb) instead of Intel and Nvidia drivers as I couldn't get them to work (or the hardware is simply not supported yet).

SCFB is a fairly simple driver and it does not support various features like brightness control:

> If an accelerated graphics driver is not available for your FreeBSD system, an alternative is to use the scfb driver. At the time of writing, this is a common option for laptops with Broadwell or Skylake chipsets from Intel with integrated graphics, until the Intel DRM driver is updated to include support. Whilst the scfb driver does not provide accelerated graphics, and is missing some features like brightness adjustment and support for external displays, it works fine on built-in laptop displays for simple desktop use and even playing videos.

[Source](https://wiki.freebsd.org/Graphics/SCFB).

### Question

Is there any other way to decrease brightness when running a graphical X session?

#### Details

I've already tried `xbrightness`, `xgamma`, `xbacklight` and [`sct`](http://www.tedunangst.com/flak/post/sct-set-color-temperature) to reduce screen's temperature but it doesn't work as all of them depend on X protocols.

The Intel device I'm using is *HD Graphics 5500*.

Comment: Same boat here. The description of the frame buffer driver says it is not possible....I am waiting for the next xorg version to see if they clean their act about the intel driver. see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/361243/using-native-1366-x-768-resolution-in-a-lenovo-ideapad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible as SCFB is a generic video driver, which does not support it.

---

It is worth noting, however, that the Intel driver now supports HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell), so one can use it instead of SCFB.